# angular filter - group by object (or multiple fields)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-filters

I extended the [Angular filter group by](https://github.com/a8m/angular-filter#groupby) example to the following by transforming the team to an object.

```js
     var app = angular.module('myApp',['angular.filter']);

app.controller('MainController', ['$scope', function($scope){
  $scope.players = [
  {
    name: 'Gene', 
    team: {
      'id' : '1',
      'name' : 'alpha'
      
    }
  },
  {
    name: 'George', 
    team: {
      'id' : '2',
      'name' : 'beta'
    }
  },
  {
    name: 'Steve', 
    team: {
      'id' : '3',
      'name' : 'gamma'
    }
  },
  {
    name: 'Paula', 
    team: {
      'id' : '2',
      'name' : 'beta'
    }
  },
  {
    name: 'Scruath', 
    team: {
      'id' : '3',
      'name' : 'gamma'
    }
  }
];
}]);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script data-require="angularjs@1.6.2" data-semver="1.6.2" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.2/angular.js"></script>
    <script data-require="angular-filter@*" data-semver="0.5.7" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-filter/0.5.7/angular-filter.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="MainController">
      <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="(team, players) in players | groupBy: 'team.name'">
          <a href="#I need the team ID">Group name: {{ team }}</a>
          <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="player in players">
              player: {{ player.name }}
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

But, what if I need the team id in the group by? What can I do?

```
<a href="#I need the team ID">Group name: {{ team }}</a>
```

I tried to group by the team object and use `team.name` and `team.id` but it didn't work. Also, I didn't know how to create a group by with multiple fields `(team.id, team.name)`

Here's a [working plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/KykgKLLfM57JOHNabEpA?p=preview)

Comment: after `groupBy`, you will probably have two different team id of the same group name, is this all right?

Comment: @Pengyy when I group by team, I will have 1 id and 1 name for a team. And 1 team having multiple players

Comment: Haha eddy, an other questions of you. And same as all time, wrong approach results in error =)

Comment: @lin What's wrong now? When I have a team name I need a link to click on it to see the team details, so to reach it I need the team id in the link. Solve it :p

Comment: Its not possible, due to your data format. It doesnt make sense. You group by name but e.g. team name "gamma" has 2 different IDs.

Comment: Ohlalla, sorry I didn't pay attention, I corrected it. It was a typo, each team has a unique id for sure

Comment: Does each team has a unique name too? I don't think so :)

Comment: I give a you solution with group by team.id because its much more neat. Group by name could be break due to not unique team names.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139729/discussion-between-eddyg-and-lin).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have a simple solution:

I grouped by `team.id`

```
<li ng-repeat="(teamid, players) in players | groupBy: 'team.id'">
```

Then I used: `players[0].team.name` within the group

```
<li ng-repeat="(teamid, players) in players | groupBy: 'team.id'">
    <a href="#Here I can use the group teamid">Group name: {{ players[0].team.name }}</a>
      <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="player in players">
          player: {{ player.name }}
        </li>
     </ul>
</li>
```

Since `players` in each group are only the players belonging to this group where all of them have the same team, so `players[0]`, `players[1]` and so on will have the same team name.

```js
     var app = angular.module('myApp',['angular.filter']);

app.controller('MainController', ['$scope', function($scope){
  $scope.players = [
  {
    name: 'Gene', 
    team: {
      'id' : '1',
      'name' : 'alpha'
      
    }
  },
  {
    name: 'George', 
    team: {
      'id' : '2',
      'name' : 'beta'
    }
  },
  {
    name: 'Steve', 
    team: {
      'id' : '3',
      'name' : 'gamma'
    }
  },
  {
    name: 'Paula', 
    team: {
      'id' : '2',
      'name' : 'beta'
    }
  },
  {
    name: 'Scruath', 
    team: {
      'id' : '3',
      'name' : 'gamma'
    }
  }
];
}]);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script data-require="angularjs@1.6.2" data-semver="1.6.2" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.2/angular.js"></script>
    <script data-require="angular-filter@*" data-semver="0.5.7" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-filter/0.5.7/angular-filter.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="MainController">
      <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="(teamid, players) in players | groupBy: 'team.id'">
          <a href="#Here I can use the group teamid">Group name: {{ players[0].team.name }}</a>
          <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="player in players">
              player: {{ player.name }}
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should group by `team.id` because a team name is not unique. In that way you avoid a wrong data output. Ok, well. I was able to solve your problem by pre-collecting your team in the controller and normalize them by `team.id`in a seperate object - [demo fiddle](http://plnkr.co/edit/b8AZ4Y6JgFMhR014oK9u?p=preview):

#### View

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
<div ng-controller="MainController">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="(team, players) in players | groupBy: 'team.id'">
            <a href="{{ team }} ">Group name: {{ teams[team].name }}</a>
            <ul>
                <li ng-repeat="player in players">
                    player: {{ player.name }}
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
</body>
```

#### AngularJS Application

```
var app = angular.module('myApp',['angular.filter']);

app.controller('MainController', ['$scope', function($scope){

    $scope.players = [
        {
            name: 'Gene',
            team: {
                'id' : '1',
                'name' : 'alpha'

            }
        }, {
            name: 'George',
            team: {
                'id' : '2',
                'name' : 'beta'
            }
        }, {
            name: 'Steve',
            team: {
                'id' : '3',
                'name' : 'gamma'
            }
        }, {
            name: 'Paula',
            team: {
                'id' : '4',
                'name' : 'beta'
            }
        }, {
            name: 'Scruath',
            team: {
                'id' : '5',
                'name' : 'gamma'
            }
        }];

    $scope.teams = {};

    $scope.players.forEach(function (player) {
        if (angular.isUndefined($scope.teams[player.team.id])) {
            $scope.teams[player.team.id] = player.team;
        }
    });
}]);
```